# Given two arrays, how to build a new array that includes only elements of one array which keys are present in the second array as values?

Tags: php, arrays, array-intersect

I've the following two arrays:

```
// array1
Array (
 [key1] => value1,
 [key2] => value2,
 [key3] => value3,
 [key4] => value4,
 [key5] => value5
)

// array2
Array (
 [0] => key1,
 [1] => key3,
 [2] => key5
)
```

I would like to build a new array that includes only elements of `array1` which *keys* are present in `array2` as *values*, so to have the following:

```
// new array
Array (
 [key1] => value1,
 [key3] => value3,
 [key5] => value5
)
```

How can I make that (maybe using something like arrays intersection)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_intersect_key` and `array_flip`. See this [working demo](https://3v4l.org/LMQj6).

```
$a = [
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3',
    'key4' => 'value4',
    'key5' => 'value5',
];

$b = ['key1', 'key3', 'key5'];

$c = array_intersect_key($a, array_flip($b));

print_r($c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse your `$array2` so that the values become keys and vice versa. After that, use `array_intersect_key` to get common keys.

```
$reverseArray = array_flip($array2);
var_dump(array_intersect_key($array1, $reverseArray));
```

For more information, search this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php).

Comment: A reversed array in Php suggests a reverse of order.   So not the best choice of variable name.

Comment: I see. Reverse and flip are quite similar.

Comment: I'd say that reverse and flip are quite different.